# Frequency shift keying antennas

Tags: transform

I am having trouble understanding how the antenna picks up signals that utilize FSK.

- Because FSK alters the frequency and most antennas pick up signals on a very select frequency, how exactly does it pick up the signal?
- Or does the antenna pick up on a range of frequencies. And if so, doesn't that limit the bandwidth?

I am having this question, because when one tunes a radio to a certain signal, it picks up signals of that frequencies only. But I believe radio stations use FSK to transmit their data also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antennas don't just work for a single frequency and for nothing else. They typically work for a larger range of frequencies. We call the total amount of frequencies their bandwidth.

So although FSK uses a set of carrier frequencies, all of these are typically well-received by a single antenna.

Yes, bandwidth of antennas is limited, but so is the bandwidth of the signals you want to send over the air or can even generate and process.

"Radio Stations": you probably mean FM audio broadcasts? Those are FM, not FSK; the same applies, however: though FM uses a whole bandwidth to transport a single programme, an antenna can easily pick up this whole bandwidth. In fact, normal "FM Radio" antennas capture the whole ca. 87 MHz – 108 MHz bandwidth reasonably well at all.

You seem pretty confused by a set of basic terms. I don't really know your background, but getting a clear introduction to what a signal, frequencies, bandwidth, and radio are might be a good idea before getting into concepts like FSK. In fact, I'm pretty confused by the fact that you already asked about LDPCs and now about these basic terms of radio transmission – I'd typically expect people to learn about what an antenna does and how that works with signal bandwidths a solid year before they can get to learn about LDPCs – which demands good understanding of what a radio channel is. So my intuition is that you're from a math or computer science background, and it came easier to you to understand algebraic coders than  RF channels (which would explain why you didn't immediately understand, though you showed great insight there, that deletion channels aren't that often used to model wireless communication).

Now, aside from getting a nice textbook (or the ARRL handbook, for a start) that explains a bit of RF technology basis, it might be a good idea for future questions to explain a bit of the background you have. I'm really puzzled by the "order" of your questions!

Comment: Your insight is even greater. I am from a computer science background, working on practical applications of error correction codes. Hence, I didn't have a formal learning of radio transmission, etc. I will do as you suggested. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to that doesn't have to do with the antenna. The antena of A radio receiver takes a bandwidth where lots of FSK signals appear, but the the frequency of interest is selected by a bandpass filter traditionally controles with a varactor. Then that BPF filter the bandwidth of interest inside the receiver bandwidth of the antenna. And that bandwidth contains the spectrum of the fsk modulares signal. To receiver the original base band signal, then the signal is múltiples by a Local Oscillator and then processed. This is a very basic descripción of a receiver chain, so if you are more intereses in that read more in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_modulation